# Nested Scroll View Jump on live data update data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding, android-livedata

I have a nested scroll view which has a linear layout with a few include tags. I'm using data binding to set the data. I'm updating the data using live data. However if I update the Live Data of any view which is outside the scroll, the scroll view is jumping scroll to the position of the element on each live data update.

I've been stuck with this for a while. Please help me.

Live Data updates are working fine, just facing issues with the jump of the scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the ViewGroup contained in the NestedScrollView.